# Having trouble printing out Javascript info

Tags: javascript, ajax, soundcloud

Below is the code I have and instead of it automatically adding the info to a div with the id #userid, I need to actually print out the user id (currently, it just adds it to the div, but I need to be able to just print it where ever I want, instead of it auto-adding to a div wrap).

My ultimate goal is to get the USER ID and then put it into a WordPress query (the userid is currently being used as a post tag and I need to pull all posts from that specific user, so I want to query posts by tag)

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>  
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "a808af7fabb53ad7971c6c9675f392b3",
    redirect_uri: "http://madebyguerrilla.com/clients/2012/theappreciationengine/wordpress/wp-content/themes/TheAppreciationEngine_WP/callback.html"
  });

  $("#connect").live("click", function(){
    SC.connect(function(){
      SC.get("/me", function(me){
        $("#username").text(me.username);
        $("#userid").text(me.id);
      });
    });
  });

  $("#update").live("click", function(){
    SC.put("/me", {user: {description: $("#description").val()}}, function(response, error){
      if(error){
        alert("Some error occured: " + error.message);
      }else{
        alert("Profile description updated!");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you got this far, how hard could it be to store user id in a `variable`?

Comment: This is the code that Soundcloud gives me, I didn't custom write any of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you could be new to JS? Just kidding.

Inside the `SC.get()` call you have access to the ID as `me.id`:

```
var userId;

SC.get("/me", function(me){
    $("#username").text(me.username);
    $("#userid").text(me.id); // <-- This is the user id, you can store it in a variable
    userId = me.id; //           <-- like this
});
```

Comment: ha, yes, I am actually pretty new to coding javascript :)

Thanks for the tip. So with the userId, I can print that out with php, or no? Sorry for the seemingly noob questions.

Comment: Since JavaScript is processed on the client and PHP on the server, the only way you could get that value in PHP trough this is by doing an AJAX request. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/